# how to get coordinates of the center of the viewed area in google maps using Google Maps JavaScript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How to get coordinates using javascript Google Maps JavaScript API v3 of the center of the currently viewed area on google maps? Thanks

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can call:

```
map.getCenter();
```

to return a LatLng object.

Comment: After you have the latLng obj just do this, `latLng.lat()` and `latLng.lng()`

Comment: I know this is a few years old, but I used this answer and eventually short-handed it to the following:   `var mylat = map.getCenter().lat();  
   var mylng = map.getCenter().lng();`

Comment: `map.center`, `map.center.lat()` and `map.center.long()` also works

Answer (score 18):

Updated 2018
The below codes are for Google Maps API for Android.
In case anyone needs this Script:

```
double mylat = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;               
double mylon = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
```

Comment: the question is about Javascript not Android

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug bearer for me. You have to create a pin element in the xml as such if you want a hoover over the map on centre.

```
//onMapReady
 mMap = googleMap;

//In your listener/ screen code area
 LatLng latlong = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;

HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put("Latitude", latlong.latitude);
     map.put("Longitude", latlong.longitude);
   //push to your database
```